# How to load and display QML file

Tags: qt, qml

I have two QML pages `main.qml` and `Kos.qml`,
what i want is when a button in `main.qml` clicked it load `Kos.qml` in the screen.

i did try using loader, but it is not working

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5


ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "#fc4343"
    title: qsTr("Tabs")
    visible: true

    // HALAMAN UTAMA
    Page {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: page
        enabled: true

        Loader{
            id: kos
            active: true
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 198
            width: 87
            height: 30
            text: qsTr("Search")
            font.bold: true
            anchors.top: borderImage.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 198
            anchors.right: toolSeparator.left
            anchors.rightMargin: 28
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked:{
                    kos.source = "Kos.qml";
                }

            }


            background: Rectangle {
                id: background
                color: "#ef3644"
            }

            contentItem: Text {
                id: textItem
                font: control.font
                opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                color: "white"
                text: "Search"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }
        }
   }
```

`Kos.qml` i use `PageBackground` as a background

```
import QtQuick 2.4

PageBackground {
    id: kos
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Text {
        id: element
        x: 6
        y: 20
        width: 24
        height: 32
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr("<")
        font.strikeout: false
        styleColor: "#ffffff"
        font.underline: false
        font.italic: false
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: 25
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
   }
}
```

did i messed up somewhere?

Comment: please provide source code of `Kos.qml`. i

Comment: Kos.qml added, also edited it accordingly to my progress.

Comment: Is Kos.qml in the same directory as main.qml?

Comment: yes it's in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run your code. Since I am not aware of what your `PageBackground` is, I changed that to `Rectangle`. That works for me. Try to start from the minimal code then add your styles and functions on top of it. Try with below minimal code. Keep both main.qml & Kos.qml in the same directory and ensure both files added to qml resources.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "App window"
    }

    Loader {
        id: loaderId
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: ""
    }

    Button {
        text: "click me!!"
        width: parent.width
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        onClicked: {
            if(loaderId.source == "")
                loaderId.source = "Kos.qml"
            else
                loaderId.source = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Kos.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Rectangle {
    id: kos
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "grey"

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "<b>Loaded Item</b>"
        color: "white"
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still doesn't work on my machine, but i sent the code to my friend and it works. still don't know what's going on.

Comment: Does it show any runtime error? Which version of Qt, OS you are using?

Comment: it doesn't show any error whatsoever. i use Qt 5 open source version along with felgo. Windows 10 OS